# After button click session expiring using thread asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

Below is my button click code expiring session in all page after click

```
protected void btnscreenshot_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    allpanels.Visible = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(GenerateThumbnail);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

}
```

How to manage session is expiring after button click, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

**First Way**

**Session State is only access when enableSessionState is Set to True...**

In Page Directory....You Have to set

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testing_frmTest" EnableSessionState="True"%>
```

Or In web.conig include this in System.web...

```
<pages enableSessionState = "true" />
```

**Second Way**

Create a separate method and  stored Session with in thread

```
 protected void btnscreenshot_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        var threadexample = new Thread(() =>
        {
            dt = GetData();
        });
        threadexample.Start();
        threadexample.Join();
        Session["ThreadTesting"] = dt;

    }
    protected DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       //Do Your Process
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: <pages enableSessionState = "true" /> this also not workiing. @akhilesh singh

Comment: bro i think solution is : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/470480/Creating-thread-results-in-session-time-out-in-IIS .@akhilesh singh